# Partitioning using column from different table

Tags: sql-server, performance, database-design, partitioning, maintenance

I have a table `ActionValues` with the following columns:

1. `AccountID`
2. `Action`
3. `ActionValue`

This table is related with a second table called `Actions` that has the following columns:

1. `AccountID`
2. `Action`
3. `ActionDateTime`

I would like to partition the `ActionValues` with a partition scheme that allows me to maintain 12 partitions (1 for each month of the year). Every month, the oldest partition would be truncated/merged and a new one would be added. To do this, I need to create a clustered index on a column from the original `ActionValues` table. However, I can only get this information from the `Actions` with the `AccountID`/`Action` relation.

Would it be possible to create a clustered index on the `ActionValues` table using the `ActionDateTime` column? Do I need to create an extra column in `ActionValues` to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be possible to create a clustered index on the ActionValues
> table using the ActionDateTime column?

Nope

> Do I need to create an extra column in ActionValues to achieve this?

Yes

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver16#partitioning-column
your partitioning column must be regular column so you should de-normalize your table.

Please note column ActionValues do not have to be the first of your clustered index.